# What are the minimum permissions needed by Kafka brokers for them to operate?

Tags: kafka

I'm securing a Kafka cluster. I read and followed the [Confluent Kafka Security Tutorial](https://docs.confluent.io/current/tutorials/security_tutorial.html#brokers), and it works like a charm.

Now, I would like to add ACLs to the brokers in order to remove them from the super users list (`super.users=User:kafkabroker`).

What is the minimum set of ACLs needed by the brokers so they can communicate and operate properly?

Answer (score 0):

Write/read for log location (where the messages are stored). That's all as far as I know in the basic setup. If the cluster is secured then you might want to take a look here https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-security-authorization-authentication-encryption/